# Ftp download file is slow in Nodejs 10.15.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I'm running an ftp client.
When downloading a file from the ftp server it is very slow using the version of nodejs 10.15.0.

But when I use version 8 of nodejs it does it fast, as it should be.

That is my problem and I would like to know how to solve it.

This is the base code

```
var PromiseFtp = require('promise-ftp');
  var fs = require('fs');

  var ftp = new PromiseFtp();
  ftp.connect({host: host, user: user, password: password})
  .then(function (serverMessage) {
    return ftp.get('foo.txt');
  }).then(function (stream) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      stream.once('close', resolve);
      stream.once('error', reject);
      stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('foo.local-copy.txt'));
    });
  }).then(function () {
    return ftp.end();
  });
```

Comment: What is "slow" and "fast"? Like 1min/5sec?

Comment: When I refer to slow to download a file of 20kb in 30 seconds and in nodejs 8 the download is instantly (as it should be)

Comment: From what you have posted we don't really know enough to resolve your issue. Has anything else changed? Service provider, connection speed? Have you tried other ftp packages?

Comment: I have used different packages (almost all), but I get the same result with nodejs 10. I feel that Nodejs is limiting the processes

Comment: From the [node 10 changelog](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v10.0.0/), it doesn't appear that anything related changed.

Comment: I'm using Node.js v10.15.1 and tried your code to download a 350KB file from a very remote FTP site. It just cost 6 seconds. Wish this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I have the same issue.
But I think it's not the dowload that is slow, but the close of stream.

For example, I download a 135 MB file.
That's take 32 secondes but really just 2 secondes to download and 30 seconds to close the stream.